# macOS appName not show the newest on the dock and Application directory

Tags: macos, electron-builder

My old app that name is `dd`.

Now we rename the app to `me` and change the icon by updating.

Newest app is built by `electron-builder` for acrossing the platform.

After upgrading the app can run correctly but the app name not changed on `the dock` and `the Finder Application directory`.

The icon changed immediately on Finder Application directory but on the `dock` must complete quit and restart the icon will be changed.

App name will never change to the new name.

I have try to set  `resource/xx.lproj/InfoPlist.strings` that not working too.

`InfoPlist.strings`

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "new app name";
"CFBundleName" = "new app name";
```

Does anyone know what's going on and how to solve this problem?

Sorry for my English

Comment: Try deleting your app and reinstall it.

Comment: @Turtleeeeee In my company this app has four hundred thousand users. I can not make everyone to do that...It's best to do it programmatically

Comment: Did you set Bundle Display Name to ${PRODUCT_NAME} in your info.plist?

Comment: Yes I did..., This case is old app updrage to the new(The technical architecture has changed, they have same bundle id and signature), If I install new app directly everything is correct.

Comment: It would be nice if Apple supported refreshing the specific app info

Comment: There is no such an API, App's info will be refreshed after every upgrade. I think it's still an erroneous configuration cause. You should referee again your configuration of info.plist. Its name should be properly right, provided you've made everything right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution.

First after the app run 3s do below code

```
execSync('mv /Applications/Old.app /Applications/NewName.app')
```

Why after running 3s(undetermine, may less or more)? Because I rename immediately the app will crash. If delay some times, It works.

Then I parsed `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist` to get the app index by `bundle-identifier` and `file-label` and `_CFURLString`

Then, execute some command line code in `child_process`

```
// delete the app on the dock by index
execSync(`plutil -remove  persistent-apps.${index} ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist`
```

```
execSync(`plutil -insert persistent-apps.${index} -xml "<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>/Applications/NewAppName.app</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>0</integer></dict></dict></dict>" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist & killall Dock`)
```

Last

```
spawn('open', ['-n', '-a', '/Applications/NewAppName.app']);
app.quit();
```

This solution will make flash the screen once for refresh `the dock`.